# Probability- Binomial Distribution formula

Tags: probability

$$b(x,n,p)= {n \choose x} \times p^x \times (1-p)^{n-x}$$

Is ${n \choose x}$ the number of orderings in which successes can be chosen from the outcomes?

Is $p^x$ the total probability of the successes occurring? Each time a success occurs we add one to the exponent

Is $(1-p)^{n-x}$ the total number of failures that occur?

Does the formula then mean to take the total orderings of the way in which successes can occur by the total probability of it occurring and not occurring? Why would we want the probability of failures involved?

Answer (score 1):

In sum, the answers to all your questions are YES.

Notice that the underlying context of binomial distribution is that it is consisted of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli tries. Let's say for the Bernoulli try, you have probability $p$ to get result $1$, and $1-p$ to get result $0$.

So binomial cares about if I do $n$ times of Bernoulli tries, what is the probability that I get exactly $x$ times of result $1$ (and thus, $n-x$ times of result $0$).

Thus firstly you need to know how many outcomes are there that we get exact $x$ times of result $1$ (i.e. $n \choose x$). And you probably noticed that each such outcome has the same probability due to the i.i.d. property. And the probability could be to getting $x$ result $1$ (i.e. $p^x$), and $n-x$ result $0$ (i.e. $(1-p)^{n-x}$)

Answer (score 0):

> Is ${n \choose x}$ the number of orderings in which successes can be chosen from the outcomes?

Yes. $n\choose x$ counts selections of $x$ elements from a set of $n$.

In this case, we count ways we can select trials where successes *may* occur.

> Is $p^x$ the total probability of the successes occurring? Each time a success occurs we add one to the exponent

Yes, $p^x$ is the probability that those $x$ selected trials are in fact successes.   (The trials are independent and identically distributed with success rate $p$.)

> Is $(1-p)^{n-x}$ the total number of failures that occur?

Yes, $(1-p)^{n-x}$ is the probability that the $n-x$ trials which were not selected will in fact be failures.

> Does the formula then mean to take the total orderings of the way in which successes can occur by the total probability of it occurring and not occurring?

That is so: It is the probability that *some* selection of $x$ from $n$ trials will be successes *and the remainder will be failures*.

> Why would we want the probability of failures involved?

Because we want the probability that we have *exactly* $x$ successes among the $n$ trials.   Which is also the probability that we have *exactly* $n-x$ failures among $n$ trials.

---

This is in essence an application of the Law of Total Probability.

EG: The probability for two successes among three trials: $$\mathsf P(SSF\cup SFS\cup FSS) ~=~ pp(1-p)+p(1-p)p+(1-p)pp = \binom 32 p^2 (1-p)^{3-2}$$